# Clearing the most significant bit

Tags: go, binary

I have a file containing two bytes, in Big Endian order, `hexdump` gives me:

`81 50`

which is `1000 0001 0101 0000` in binary. However, I want the most significant bit to be a flag, so in golang I have to load the file content, clear the most significant bit, and only then read the value.

So:

```
valueBuf := make([]byte, 2)
_, err := f.Read(valueBuf) // now printing valueBuf gives me [129 80] in decimal
value := int16(binary.BigEndian.Uint16(valueBuf[0:2])) // now value is -32432
```

Ok, I have tried to use something like:

```
func clearBit(n int16, pos uint) int16 {
    mask := ^(1 << pos)
    n &= mask
    return n
}
```

But it apparently doesn't work as expected. The output value should be `336` in decimal, as normal int, and I cannot get it. How should I do this?

Comment: What is the format of the least significant 15 bits? Can they be negative, or is it unsigned?

Comment: Yeah, reads to me like you probably want `uint16`. I guess you might be separating the steps for example code, but I'd also just [`encoding.Read`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) right into the `uint16` instead of reading and converting separately.

Answer (score 3):

for `n &= mask` to work, `n` and `mask` have to be matching types. So you should write

```
mask := int16(^(1 << pos))
```

then, `value = clearBit(value, 15)` works fine.

Or, since constants are untyped, you can eliminate `mask`, and also eliminate the assignment to `n` since it's just returned on the following line, and shorten `clearBit` to

```
func clearBit(n int16, pos uint) int16 {
    return n & ^(1 << pos)
}
```